# AirPod not working on MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: airpods

I just got my airpord new and I noticed It keeps disconnecting from my laptop it works fine with my phone but at times works on my laptop and at times it doesn’t

Comment: Do you have an apple watch? AirPods once set up with your devices, are accessible with all of your other devices on your account. They could be connected to your phone or another apple device while you are using the computer. To prove this try connecting to your computer and then turn off the Bluetooth on your iPhone and see if it persists. If you have another Apple device nearby like an Apple Watch or iPad, it may attempt to connect to it if its in range.

Comment: The funny thing is I do turn off all other device Bluetooth at times it would work with the laptop and at times it won't but it works well on all other apple device expect for mac laptop's I even tried it on another mac which does not even belong to me still same it will even connect and be making some weird noise and then disconnect